# Acceso a elementos dentro de otro ContentPlaceHolder ASP:NET

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de acceder a un elemento Label dentro de otro ContentPlaceHolder, pero no logro que el objeto creado a partir del contenido en ese se pueda acceder a las propiedades desde el otro.

La **MasterPage** está escrita así:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="PruebaMasterPage.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Titulo" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Barra" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblCPHTitulo" runat="server" Text="Este es un ejemplo de Label"></asp:Label>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Formulario" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

El **WebForm** está escrito así, no tiene nada incluido aún:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="PruebaMasterPage.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Titulo" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Barra" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="Formulario" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Y el **Behind Code** está escrito en C# así:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PruebaMasterPage
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("Barra");
            Label label = (Label)cph.FindControl("lblCPHTitulo");

            label.Text = "Hola mundo!";
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo **obtengo el siguiente error**:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

label fue null.

Los **detalles del error** son los siguientes:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Mensaje = Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
  Origen = PruebaMasterPage
  Seguimiento de la pila:
   en PruebaMasterPage.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) en D:\pruebas\PruebaMasterPage\WebForm1.aspx.cs: línea 13
```

No encuentro la causa del error. Alguien puede orientarme en este caso?

Gracias por su atención.